# How do I declare 2 associations on 1 model as 2 different types?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I have an `Order` & `User` model.

Each `Order` `belongs_to` a `User`.

Each `User` has different roles - `buyer, vendor, admin`.

Each `Order` will contain many `Items`. Each `Item` can be from a different `user_id` (which is basically a user with a role of `vendor`).

What I would like to do, is to be able to specify that each `Order` can `has_many :vendors`.

A `vendor` is not a model, but rather a role of `User`.

So how do I declare that association such that I can do this:

```
@order = Order.last
@order.vendors
```

That will then show me all the vendors associated with all the items in that 1 Order.

Comment: Have you tried, in your Order model, `has_many :vendors, :class_name => 'User'` ?

Comment: I have not. Let me try that and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
has_many :vendors, :class_name => 'User', :conditions => { :role => "vendor" }
```